# How to resolve free(): invalid pointer error while assigning multiple variables in a doubly linked list?

Tags: c++, string, doubly-linked-list

C++ newbie here.

I have 2 data variables in my doubly linked list; instr_num and opcode. When I copy a value into instr_num, it works, but throws an error when I do it for opcode.

```
struct Node {
    int instr_num;
    std::string opcode;
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* prev;
};

void initialize_DLL(Node** tail, Node** head, int s_instr_num, string s_opcode) {
    Node* new_node = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        exit(1);
        return;
    }
    
    new_node->instr_num = s_instr_num; // THIS EXECUTES
    new_node->opcode = s_opcode;        // THIS THROWS AN ERROR:  free(): invalid pointer
    new_node->prev = NULL;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    
    *tail = new_node;
    *head = new_node;
}

int main(){
    Node* tail = NULL;
    Node* head = NULL;
    std::string temp_opcode = "ADD"
    
    initialize_DLL(&tail, &head, 1, temp_opcode);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm guessing it might have to do something with malloc, but I'm not sure. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing in your allocated `Node` will be initialized. Use `new` in C++.

Comment: `struct int instr_num;` Does this even compile?

Comment: Basically you have _undefined behavior_, no one can reproduce that based on only that information.

Comment: why did you use `malloc` ? This is not how you create an instance. `malloc` is rather special with quite rare and narrow use cases. If you are a beginner you can forget that it exists for quite a while. I never had to use it

Comment: @Zoso my bad. I had a struct there before, missed to remove it when I posted it. It's just int instr_num.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I was referring to a C tutorial, and trying to code the same in C++, missed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, you would use `new` to initialize the allocated memory:

```
#include <string>
#include <utility>

struct Node {
  int instr_num;
  std::string opcode;
  Node* next;
  Node* prev;
};

void initialize_DLL(Node** tail, Node** head, int s_instr_num,
                    std::string s_opcode) {
  *tail = *head =
      new Node{s_instr_num, std::move(s_opcode)};  // NULLs are implicit
}

int main() {
  Node* tail = NULL;
  Node* head = NULL;
  std::string temp_opcode = "ADD";

  initialize_DLL(&tail, &head, 1, temp_opcode);

  delete tail;  // don't leak
}
```

Note that playing with raw pointers is dangerous.

In C, you would use a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Node {
  int instr_num;
  struct Node* next;
  struct Node* prev;
  char opcode[];
};

void initialize_DLL(struct Node** tail, struct Node** head, int s_instr_num,
                    char const* s_opcode) {
  size_t str_sz = strlen(s_opcode) + 1;
  *tail = *head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node) + str_sz);

  if (!*head)
    return;

  (*head)->instr_num = s_instr_num;
  (*head)->next = NULL;
  (*head)->prev = NULL;
  memcpy((*head)->opcode, s_opcode, str_sz);
}

int main() {
  struct Node* tail = NULL;
  struct Node* head = NULL;
  char const* temp_opcode = "ADD";

  initialize_DLL(&tail, &head, 1, temp_opcode);

  free(head);
}
```

The "flexible array member" concept doesn't exist in C++. You could use an array of 1 char to emulate something similar but indexing other characters would be undefined behavior according to the C++ standard. So, don't use that in C++, unless your compiler explicitly allows and you're OK with non-portable code.

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm catching up with C++, I'll pay more attention to what I shouldn't do in C++ that I do in C.

Comment: I have a follow-up question. If I change my original struct to:
```
struct Node {
 struct my_data;
 Node* next;
 Node* prev;
};

struct my_data{
 int instr_num;
    std::string opcode;
};
```
How do I create initialize the allocated memory using `new` ?

Comment: @ObviousActivity936 https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/z8Wo4K1cY